# kafka consumer not reporting to consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we have setup a single node kafka cluster and running the consumers app on other server(around 10 consumers running). When i am trying to get the consumer details from kafka command line i can see few consumers are not reporting to the consumer as i get just the headers of the command output and not the actual kafka consumer details.

```
user@kafkaserver:/home/kafka/kafka$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server <brokerip>:9092 --describe --group <group_name>
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).


TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
```

Server on which consumers are running is able to connect to broker server on port 9092 and also to zookeeper. Could this be an issue on the consumer?

Comment: Are you passing a valid `group-name`? You must provide some details regarding your topic (e.g. how many partitions) and your consumers in order to be able to help you out.

Comment: What do you mean "also to Zookeeper"? As of Kafka 0.9, consumers really shouldn't be using Zookeeper. In other words, what consumer code do you have?

Comment: Is it single consumer or multiple consumers (as mentioned around 10 above)? are you using the group.id config you have used for this app in place of <group_name>?

Comment: There are multiple consumer. and none of the consumer is reporting to consumer group.